# How to extract variable from integral

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Can I extract x from the expression
$$Ax+B\int x \, dt $$
So I can get some expression like this?
$$(A + BK)x$$

Comment: Since $\int x dt=x t+K$, then  $Ax+B \int x dt=Ax+B(xt+k)$

Comment: @riksaars: Where is your equation ? What you show are not equation since there is no $=$ in it. Moreover : is $x$ function of $t$ or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no typo in the expression (you typed what you meant), then note that $\int x dt = tx$ modulo constants (i.e. $\int x dt$ having the form $tx + K$ where $K \in \mathbb{R}$) by the definition of primitive, where $x$ is supposed to be a given number. Then you surely can do the rest re-writing-in-another-form job. If there is some typo in the expression, most likely you mean $\int x dx$ instead of $\int x dt$, then note that $\int x dx = x^{2}/2$ modulo constants by the definition of primitive. You can do the rest.